# How can I embed programming source code in Powerpoint slide and keep code highlighting?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, source-code

Is it possible to embed **programming source code** to Powerpoint slide, and keep code highlighting/coloring?

Comment: what application are you copying from?

Comment: I use textmate, e-texteditor and eclipse the most.

Comment: Please copy your code to VC Code, and then paset to  ppt

Answer (score 67):

After pasting, a small "Paste Options" icon appears below the pasted text.

Click this icon and choose "Keep Source Formatting" :

[image]

Comment: I don't see such a `Paste Options` icon. I don't see a button to give me these options. I'm using PowerPoint:mac 2011. I think I have seen it in Windows versions, however.

Comment: I tried different suggested methods and tools to copy from, but was actually missing that word/powerpoint was messing up the format by using "Destination Theme". Thanks!

Answer (score 58):

Use Notepad++ with add-on NppExport.

- Select the source code
- Use Copy RTF to clipboard of NppExport
- Paste into empty PPT slide (do not select any textfiled)

Comment: With version 6.9.2 or higher it's working without NppExport plugin. Just make right-click on the selected text -> Plugin commands -> Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: Current version of Notepad++ already comes with this plugin :)

Comment: Still working in NPP v8.2.1, Power Point 2016

Comment: Direct copy to PowerPoint did not worked well, I paste the code to Word and copy it from word to PowerPoint

Answer (score 32):

[Pygments](http://pygments.org/) can format almost every format to rtf:

```
pygmentize -f rtf -o code.rtf code.py
```

Comment: An online translator is available at http://pygments.org/demo/

Comment: Same idea, straight to the OS X clipboard `pygmentize -f rtf code.py | pbcopy`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I got very favorable results with `pygmentize -O style=paraiso-dark -f rtf -l aspx-cs Index.cshtml | pbcopy` for syntax highlighting of a Razor view for use in a presentation.

Comment: Adding to what @ChristianLong suggested, but for Linux: `pygmentize -f rtf code.py | xclip -sel clip`. Note that you will probably have to install xclip.

Answer (score 6):

If the source code does not need to be copied and pasted out of the presentation, a quick and dirty solution could be to simply take screenshots of the source code.

Comment: Image can be fuzzy when zoom in.

Comment: Use the magnifier and then take a screenshot of that.

Comment: Doing so can increase the size of the presentation file significantly.

Comment: This also has the drawback that once screenshot, it is no longer possible to resize the column width. This becomes a problem if you try to fit a 80 column printout into a 2x1 horizontal slide layout, a 132 column source into a 1x2 vertical layout, for example. The `pygmentize` answer above doesn't suffer from this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on Insert → Object → OpenDocument Text
2. Paste on opened panel
3. Click outside.

Note: Copying from Notepad++ will preserve colors and styling.

Comment: Doesn't work for power point 2010. I copied text from Notepad++ to Power point presentation but it looses colors and styling.

Comment: If I use NPPExport pluging and use "copy  RTF to clipboard" and then paste it works.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the code and first paste that code into Microsoft word

[image]

Then do the formatting if necessary and then copy from word and paste back to powerpoint by right clicking and choosing use destination theme

[image]

Comment: Either way,  what does “Then do the formatting if necessary” mean?

Comment: It means if you want to do some changes of your own like aligning or indentation of code

Comment: This was the only way that I could copy and paste code from IntelliJ (a special program used for writing code)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

1. Find an online source code syntax highlighting service.

   - https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/syntax_highlight.html
   - https://pinetools.com/syntax-highlighter
2. Paste the code to highlight into the web site.
3. Copy the highlighted version.
4. Create a new Word document.
5. Paste the code into Word (note the background colours may be lost).
6. Copy the code from Word.
7. Create a new text area in PowerPoint.
8. Click the **Home** menu option.
9. Open **Paste** on the ribbon.
10. Select **Keep source formatting**.
11. Optionally, change the text area background colour to taste.

Adjust the font using [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata) or other monospace font.

Answer (score 1):

Online syntax highlighter like TextMate seems good as well, http://markup.su/highlighter/

But after pasting into PowerPoint presentation new lines and line spacing is lost, so we can take a screen shot of the preview and paste it in our PowerPoint presentation

Comment: Pasting into ppt does not quite work here on Windows 10: The new lines are not pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++ and Npp Export works great, but your text will end up with a white background.

To remove it, paste first the text in word with the "preserve source formatting" option. Then, select the text and in Home > Font, remove the background with the Text Highlight Color option.

Then, copy again the text from word, and paste it in powerpoint with the "preserve source formatting" option.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting from Eclipse should retain formatting if the app supports it.  I know Word does... not sure about PPT.

Comment: Works from Eclipse Juno to Word 2010, but not to Powerpoint 2010 - it loses the colours and converts some of them to bold text

Answer (score 0):

I've had no success pasting into Powerpoint 2010 on Windows.

However, pasting from Eclipse into Word 2010 works.

You can then save this formatted text as an RTF file, then embed the RTF into a Powerpoint 2010 slide using Insert Object (and optionally select 'link' so you can edit and update the text in Word).